# .save() not correctly saving to mongoDB with async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

I'm having an issue with refactoring a function used to create a "post", which then saves it on a "user". It works just fine with the `.then()` syntax, but I can't seem to figure out how to make this work with async/await.

The post is created, and when I look at the User it is supposed to be saved to, the post id shows up on the User. However, the Post never gets a reference to the User id when created. This is what I have currently.

```
  const create = async (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.params.id;
  try {
    const foundUser = await db.User.findById(userId);
    const createdPost = await db.Post.create(req.body);
    foundUser.posts.push(createdPost._id);
    await foundUser.save((err) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
    });
    res.json({ post: createdPost });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error) console.log(error);
    res.json({ Error: "No user found."})
  }
}
```

EDIT: As requested, here is a snippet of my schema for posts.

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    
    const postSchema = new Schema(
      {
        title: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
          maxlength: 100,
        },
        description: {
          type: String,
          maxlength: 300,
        },
        date: {
          type: Date,
          default: Date.now(),
        },
        user: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "User",
        },
        comments: [
          {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Comment",
          },
        ],
      },
      { timestamps: true }
    );
    
    const Post = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);
    
    module.exports = Post;
```

Comment: add  **await**  `await foundUser.posts.push(createdPost._id);`

Comment: Could you share us your Schema codes? Did you create ref: User in Post schema?

Comment: This is what I'm using to reference my User schema on the Post schema:                  user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },

Comment: @selcuk I tried adding an await on the .push line, but it doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: `foundUser.save()` does **not** return a promise if you pass a callback function... [_"Returns undefined if used with callback or a Promise otherwise."_](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-save)

Comment: createdPost probably won't _have_ an _id field until after you save it.

Comment: Provide your `.then` way.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is probably here, you're saving the document, but the await here does nothing since you're passing a callback function, so your code does not wait for the response.

```js
await foundUser.save((err) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
});
```

There's no need to catch any errors here either since you're in a try catch, so the correct line of code here would be
`await foundUser.save()`

Answer (score 0):

So, I decided to take a look back at my way of doing this function while using .then(), and I noticed there was a line that I at first thought was unnecessary. I added `req.body.user = userId` after finding the User. This then gave me the reference to the User on my Post. So, I tried this with my async-await version and it worked! I'm not sure if this is the "right" way to go about this though.

Below I've included the working code:

```
const create = async (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.params.id;
  try {
    const foundUser = await db.User.findById(userId);
    req.body.user = userId;
    const createdPost = await db.Post.create(req.body);
    foundUser.posts.push(createdPost._id);
    await foundUser.save();
    res.json({ post: createdPost });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error) console.log(error);
    res.json({ Error: "No user found."})
  }
}
```