# Why is the object I get after saving in mongodb null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an endpoint which saves an object in a mongodb. After it finished, i try to get the same object but it is null.

```
router.post('/', async function(req, res, next) {
  const object = {req. ...}
  await saveObject(object);
  const mongoObject = await getObject(object.name); //null, but has value after second call
  res.send(object)
}

async function saveObject(...){
 ...
 await newObject.save(function (err, doc) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
    });
}

async function getObject(...){
 const object = await table.objectTable.find({...});
 return object;
}
```

(both functions "save" and "get" are working properly individually)

I debugged it and it makes no difference, how long i wait in line "res.send". So.. although i wait after these two function calls, the object is only saved, after leaving the anonymous function.

Is it possible, that some async calls have conditions in JS before they are executed. For example "only save after leaving the scope of the caller" or "wait for http traffic, then sync with db".

Comment: can you also add `saveObject` and `getObject` details?

Comment: good idea! But it's really as simple as it gets. Just saving and loading (see above)

Comment: Can you post the full code and the schema declaration as well?

Comment: You’re passing a function to save **and** awaiting it—pick an async paradigm and stick with it.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks! I need to read more about async in JS, i guess..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dave mentioned, passing the callback function was the problem.

The answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68107327/save-not-correctly-saving-to-mongodb-with-async-await) explain it.